# Two results of monotone operators of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $p\times p$ real symmetric matrices such that $A\succeq B$, meaning that $A-B$ is non-negative definite. I want to prove these two results.

**First result**: $\lambda_j(A)\geq \lambda_j(B)$, $j=1,...,p$, where $\lambda_j(\cdot)$ is the $j$ eigenvalue of the respective matrix.

**Second result**: $\log(A)\succeq \log(B)$, where $\log(X)=P\text{diag}(\log\lambda_j(X))P^{\top}$ and $X$ is a $p\times p$ symmetric matrix with spectral decomposition $X=P\text{diag}(\lambda_j(X))P^{\top}$.

I think that the two results must be straightforward. My complication is that $A$ and $B$ have (in general) different spectral decompositions, say 
$$A=PDP^{\top}$$
and
$$B=QMQ^{\top}.$$ 
It will be helpful if, for example, I can say something about $P$ and $Q$, like $P^{\top}Q=I$, which I think it could be false in general.

Comment: Your second result will only hold if we also have $B \succ 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first result, it suffices to use the [Courant-Fischer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_theorem).  In particular, we have a proof to the effect of 
$$
\lambda_j(A) = \min\{\max_x\{x^TAx : \cdots\}\} = 
\min\{\max_x\{x^TBx + x^T(A-B)x : \cdots\}\}\\
\leq
\min\{\max_{x}\{x^TBx: \cdots\}\} = \lambda_j(B).\\
$$
Your second result will only hold if we have $B \succ 0$.  In this case, your statement is equivalent to saying that the matrix-logarithm is "operator monotone" over the positive definite matrices. For a reference on this, I recommend Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* or Horn and Johnson's *Topics in Matrix Analysis*.

Comment: I think it could be easier to prove the first result with Rayleigh theorem presented in Horn and Johnson's Matrix Analysis of 2012. I've done a little research for the second and it seems that it is not straightforward to prove it.

Comment: I thought about that, but with H+J's Rayleigh theorem you're maximizing a Rayleigh quotient over two different sets, so there's no longer an obvious way to say that one objective function should be different from the other